# E-commerce project with users cart

Tags: php, security, e-commerce

I want to create an e-commerce project online. I have this issue :

- if the user is not logged in, then the selected products will be automatically added to a default cart under the name of `guest001`, `guest002` etc where `guestxxx` is a default user.
- if the user signs up, then the system will automatically check in his carts data to add it to his new account
- when the user then wants to add new products to cart, they will be added directly to his cart.

My questions are :

- Should I be using cookies to store the data in the user's machine, so it will be used by the system once the user creates his account? or should I use server side session data?
- Should I be creating a default client (`guestxxx`) in the database once the unknown user adds something to his cart, or just create a cookie to store the data without the need to create a guest user?

Comment: These sound like questions on quite separate issues.  On StackOverflow, it's preferable to focus on one topic per posted question.

Comment: Thank you Oli, I will edit it to the most important issue :)

Comment: You won't have access to the visitor's MAC address unless you install something on their machine. I don't think many people will be happy about that.

Can I ask why you're writing this from scratch, rather than adapting one of the many free or commercial systems already widely used?

Comment: Too many things being asked here, try and break them down. Also cast your eyes over the sister sites, many of these questions would be more appropriate on them: http://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: Because I have to set up the project from scratch, the company I work for must create frameworks for other people , you know : I don't use the frameworks and libraries , but I have to create them for other people to use them

Comment: @kev :) thank you friend , I just removed the last 2 issues, and saves only the first issue .

Comment: Hi Simo, "What's better? X or Y?" isn't really a question that's answerable: different contexts and different projects have different requirements. Rather than trying to ask a zero-sum question, consider working through the issues yourself first and asking a specific question when/if you get stuck.

Comment: thank you mark , you're right, I'm still working on this :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just have little suggestion for you. 
If you are using Codeigniter Framework you can use [Library Cart Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/cart.html)
 or you want make code yourself.

According to my experience. I was used session for store cart while users checkout I add his cart into my database. 
**Disadvantage** of using it while browser is closed your guest cart will start from default (no cart),

If you use cookie for it while browser is closed your guest cart will keep exist. ( store in browser ). But I think you can use both of it. Use cookie for keep cart data and use session for processing cart in your PHP Code. because Cookie is stored in browser, malicious user can do malicious activity of it.

For client i think you can use session or cookie rather than add his data into database
Hope it can help you. I just know little about it.

Comment: Thank you friend , I've fixed all those issues , +1 

I am sorry because I did not visited stackoverflow from 4 Sep :-)